# returning components following setState

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code :

```
getModal = e => {
  this.setState(
    {
      name: e.name,
      game: e.packers
    },
    () => {
      return (<Modal name={this.state.name} game={this.state.game} />);
    }
  );
};
data = {
  name: "jack sparrow",
  game: "packer wins"
};

setModal = () => {
  var a = popModal.show(this.getModal(data));
};
```

I am unable to return the Modal component. I don't know if its syntactically correct or not. When I click a button the setModal gets activated . I am able to get console results but returning a component has not been possible. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not doing anything with the return, What is that supposed to do?

Comment: I am trying to render the component Modal. I am trying out the features of react and wondering if rendering a component this way is possible or not. Thank you

Comment: I am not sure what is `popModal` but it's possible you need `ReactDom.render` there.

Comment: @Sulthan the popModal is a validator. When I return Modal outside of the setState it works but the state value is not updated due to its async nature that is why I tried to attach the Modal as a callback function but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return components from `setState` for multiple reasons, the biggest being that is an async function and running `setState` does not instantly change the content of the state. with that stated

lets look at your code below

```
this.setState(
    {
      name: e.name,
      game: e.packers
    },
    () => {
      return (<Modal name={this.state.name} game={this.state.game} />);
    }
  )
```

the function provided to the `setState` is just a callback method. basically it is a function that setState runs after it has successfully updated the state.

---

if you are simply trying to return the modal, I suggest structuring it like this instead

```
getModal = e => {
  this.setState(
    {
      name: e.name,
      game: e.packers
    });
  return (<Modal name={e.name} game={e.packers} />);
}
```

doing so will ensure that `getModal` does indeed return your modal component. however, if you wish for modal's name and game props to change with the state of this component, then I would suggest moving this to the render method instead.